# Laravel session id changes with each request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.0 site where the frontend JS makes a lot of ajax calls to the backend Laravel code. I've noticed that on each ajax request I'm getting a new "laravel_session" cookie value in the response everytime.  I'm guessing that this is some security mechanism to protect against session hijacking.

However I think this is causing an issue with my site, as my ajax calls often happen in parallel, not sequentially.  I don't wait for the response before firing the next call.

Consider this scenario

. Ajax call 1 -  request - laravel_session cookie = '1234'

. Ajax call 1 -  response - laravel_session cookie = '2345'

. Ajax call 2 -  request- laravel_session cookie = '2345'

. Ajax call 3 -  request- laravel_session cookie = '2345'

. Ajax call 2 -  response - laravel_session cookie = '3456'

. Ajax call 3 -  response - session  not longer valid

Is there any way around this?

I should also note that sessions are set to expire in  the config/session.php as
'lifetime' => 120,

[image]

[image: config/session.php]

Comment: It's not a security mechanism, and you're right - it shouldn't be happening. Check your session settings in `config/session.php`, and check that the cookie path is valid. By default, file-based sessions should be stored in `storage/framework/sessions/` - if that folder is empty, then maybe your installation can't write to that folder properly.

Comment: my settings in config/session.php look ok to me   'files' => storage_path().'/framework/sessions',
and i can see files being created in storage/framework/sessions/

Comment: for me it is 'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions')

Answer (score 12):

You are right it is a security mechanism. To disable it for testing, in Kernel.php comment out this line:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class
```

Then you will see the session ID in your cookie viewer and it doesn't change.

You can Google for HTTP encrypted cookies to learn about the practice. There is an ongoing debate if this old practice is necessary now that we use HTTPS on every website.

Comment: why do you say that ? It's not true, and you are suggesting someone to disable a security mechanism.

Comment: I'm upvoting this. The question boils down to, "why is this happening? a security thing?" and I believe this answers it. You can comment out the line to verify it, but I don't read this as a recommendation to remove the encryption.

Comment: Thanks and I edited the answer to clarify disable for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Your domain is invalid. You need to look at `config.session.domain` and `config.session.path`.

Comment: I've changed the 'domain' setting in config/session.php to the domain of my site, but still see the issue.  the 'path'  is set to '/'  which to me seems fine

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the domain is correct? Can you post another screenshot? I've had the same issues for hours until I realized I accidentally made a small mistake with it.

Comment: i've added the screenshot.  http://local.mysite.com  is the url to the site when running locally.  I have a host entry for this.

Comment: I was facing this error, and YES, THE DOMAIN was not correct. I must die. just lost 4 hours from my life. -_-

Answer (score 1):

The same issue happened with me and it was later identified that I was using

```
protected $middleware = [
     \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
     \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class
];
protected $middlewareGroups = [
     'web' => [
          \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
          \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class
     ]
]
```

in both $middleware and in $middlewaregroups because of which it was creating a new session id in movement between different routes.

Comment: so what? please explain what to do? enable both? keep only web?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I tried a lot of solutions and nothing worked for me.

**My case:**
The token keeps changing on every request only when the session driver is set to `database`, and it works just fine on `file` and `Redis` driver.

After a lot of debugging, I found that the issue was not with session config, it was from the `payload` column in the session table in the DB.

I changed the `payload` column from text to `longText`, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

There are some important things about sessions. First is cookie time. If your Laravel app's timezone is UTC but your computer's timezone is +3 then if you set your cookie lifetime 120 (two hours) then cookie will deleted by browser immediatelly. You must increase your cookie lifetime.

Other option is encryption. Cookies are always encrypted. If you set `encrypt=true` in `sessions.php` file `storage/framework/sessions` folder will be encrypted. Sometimes this causes problem. If session doesn't keep then try to set `encrypt` to `false`. After that you can see session files are unencrypted and they have 'serialized' text. Then you can see your session variables in there.

Other option is `domain` variable in `sessions.php` file. You must set it correctly or leave it `null`. Domains must not have `http(s)://` at first. Write only domain in there (for example yourdomain.com, yourdomain.test, yourdomain.host, [www.yourdomain.com](http://www.yourdomain.com), subdomain.yourdomain.com etc...).

Other option is about `driver`. If you set it to `database` then you must be sure your table columns have enough size for storing big session data. If you set it to `file` then you must be sure that `storage/framework/sessions` folder is writable and readable.

And there is a "small" (I think so important) trick. Don't use general keywords in session. For example don't use 'token' key. Use specific names for session. This is wrong: `session(['token' => $result->token])`, but this is better: `session(['backend_remote_token' => $result->token])`

Rock'n roll...

Answer (score 0):

Incase this affects anyone else.  My customer had provided a snapshot of their data, and so I was using `Carbon::setTestNow` to pretend that the current time is in a period supported by the customer's data.

This caused session cookies to be created with a timestamp in the past so that they were immediately expired by the browser.

For my simulations, I could call `Carbon::setTestNow()` again after my database queries to avoid the issue.

Wasted a few hours on it though!